# How to solve 'Storage not Initialized' errors in lwuit?

Tags: android, java-me, storage, lwuit

I have successfully ported my LWUIT app to Blackberry, touch and non touch, and MIDP. I have been able to port to Android as well, but it just loads. After that, any call to `Storage` gives me this error:

`An internal application error occured: java.lang.RuntimeException: call com.sun.lwuit.io.Storage.init(myActivity)` before using the storage mechanism!

I have added this bit of code everywhere there is a storage call in my code:

```
if(!(Storage.isInitialized())) {
    Storage.init(thestore);
}
```

`thestore` is a `String` declared at the very beginning of the code, to whatever the storage name is, and in this case its the `Activity` name. It still does not load storage. Please what else do I do? Maybe there is some permission I need to activate or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage init requires different things in different platforms specifically on Android it requires a context object from the activity. Only invoke it once after Display.init() and give it the activity instance.

[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) will eliminate the need for these hassles and only leave Display.init() in place.

Comment: Looking forward to Codename One then :) Will check the code line by line again, Thanks